# how to redirect from JSP to Action Class in Struts

Tags: jsp, struts

JSP FIle--->

```
<html:form method="post" action="/createEmployee">
    <p><font color="red">*</font>First Name</p>
    <p><html:text property="firstName" /></p>

    <p><font color="red">*</font>Last Name</p>
    <p><html:text property="lastName" /></p>

    <p><font color="red">*</font>Birth Date</p>
    <p><html:text property="birthDate" value="" /></p>

    <p><font color="red">*</font>Salary</p>
    <p><html:text property="salary" /></p>

    <p><font color="red">*</font>Organization</p>
    <p><html:text property="organization" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Save" name="submitBtn" /></p>
    <p><input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="cancelBtn" /></p>
</html:form>
```

Action Class --->

```
public ActionForward excute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("msg"));

    EmployeeForm employeeForm = (EmployeeForm)form;

    OrganizationServiceImpl organizationService = new OrganizationServiceImpl();
    long organizationId = organizationService.getOrganizationByName(employeeForm.getOrganization());
    employeeForm.setOrganization_id(organizationId);

    EmployeeServiceImpl employeeService = new EmployeeServiceImpl();
    long employeeId = employeeService.creatEmployee(employeeForm);

    request.setAttribute("employeeId", employeeId);

    return mapping.findForward("createEmployee");
}
```

I want to know whether I am giving the Action path correctly in my jsp file's ??
my action class is under "com.hr.action"

Comment: Paste your complete jsp code and struts-config mapping

Comment: Since you have this in your Jsp `action="/createEmployee"`, you should have `path=="/createEmployee"` in the action-mapping (in struts-config) for the action class. It doesn't really matter what package the action class belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to map your action to the URL in struts config xml. Check the struts config xml for the correct mappings